# Datatables briefly shows deleted rows on page load and refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the deletedatarow function to remove specific rows.  It works fine except the deleted rows briefly show on page initialization and page refresh.

I've tried deferRender, .clear, .destroy.  I am successfully removing rows containing "Siberian Husky Assessment" and "Ferret Development" however they show for a second initially.

```
<script>
$("#datatable").clear();
</script>

<script>
setTimeout(function () { $("#datatable").show() }, 50);
</script>


<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#datatable").dataTable( {
  "deferRender": true,
    "order": [ ],
  "pageLength": 600,
  "lengthMenu": [[-1, 10, 25, 50, 100], ["All", 10, 25, 50, 100]]
.clear(),
.draw();
});
  })
</script>

<script>
function deletedatarow(){
      var a = "Siberian Husky Assessment";
      var b = "Ferret Development";
      $( "tr:contains('" + a + "')").remove();
      $( "tr:contains('" + b + "')").remove();
}
deletedatarow();
</script>

<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Status Number</th>
            <th>Breed</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span>201919-0133</span></td>
            <td>Siberian Husky Assessment</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201919-0132</td>
            <td>Siberian Husky Assessment</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201919-0131</td>
            <td>Siberian Husky Assessment</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201919-0121</td>
            <td>Siberian Husky Assessment</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201919-0120</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0347</td>
            <td>Cockapoo Submitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0346</td>
            <td>Ferret Development</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0320</td>
            <td>Cockapoo Submitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0313</td>
            <td>Ferret Development</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0311</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0310</td>
            <td>Cockapoo Submitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0308</td>
            <td>Cockapoo Submitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0297</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0296</td>
            <td>Cockapoo Submitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0292</td>
            <td>Ferret Development</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0290</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0289</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0288</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0287</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0286</td>
            <td>Ferret Development</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0275</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0223</td>
            <td>Ferret Development</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0218</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0217</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0216</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0206</td>
            <td>Cockapoo Submitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0205</td>
            <td>Cockapoo Submitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0178</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0177</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0175</td>
            <td>Cockapoo Submitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0173</td>
            <td>Cockapoo Submitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0172</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0167</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0160</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0159</td>
            <td>Cockapoo Submitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0158</td>
            <td>Cockapoo Submitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0157</td>
            <td>Cockapoo Submitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0153</td>
            <td>Cockapoo Submitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0127</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0126</td>
            <td>Cockapoo Submitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0121</td>
            <td>Cockapoo Submitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0114</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0067</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0065</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0064</td>
            <td>Siberian Husky Assessment</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201918-0036</td>
            <td>Pug Characterization</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Status Number</th>
            <th>Breed</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your answer lies in the order of operations in your code.  The html is being rendered, then the dataTable function is being called (i don't think you need to call the .clear().draw() methods).  After the DataTable function is called, you are then calling your `deletedatrow()`.  It makes sense to me that you are seeing the records for a short time.

One way to get around doing that process would be to either filter out the data prior to rendering it.  Or if you are unable to do that, you could use the `createdRow` callback function as shown [here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback) and check if it matches whatever text.  If it does, remove that row.  Note that the function will be ran on every single row in the datatable though and that may be a bottleneck depending on large your result set is.